# How to withdraw the 230px from 100% width div?

Tags: html, css

The thing is, i have a sided fixed nav menu with 230px width and now I want to make a fixed top nav bar with 100% width.

But when I add any element with right float in the top navigation bar, the elements are all hidden because the bar has 100% width plus 230px from the sidebar.

```css
nav#fixed-nav-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 230px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid #191b1b;
  background-color: #141616;
  border-bottom: 1px #252525 solid;
}

nav#nav-sided {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Helvetica"; /* Tahoma */
  color: #c1c1c1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 230px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
  border-right: 1px #252525 solid;
  z-index: 8888;
}
```

```html
<nav id="fixed-nav-top">
  <div id="top-main">

  </div>
  <div id="user-area">

  </div>   
</nav>
<nav id="nav-sided"> 
  <div id="logo">
    <div class="main-logo">:)</div>
  </div>

  other stuffs
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your applicable CSS and HTML?

Comment: `width: calc(100% - 230px)`

Comment: @Vucko nicee! I would never knew that was possible lol, thanks

Comment: Couldn't you give your nav#nav-sided a top of 50px so it doesn't overlap with the top nav?

Comment: @FlashThunder In most browsers? It does. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: @Roope oh yes... they fixed that... used it few years ago... still older browsers don't support it... would simply use `margin` or `position`

Comment: But even though `calc()` does work in most browsers, there's more supported ways to do it, it's by no means necessary to use `calc()`. Why not just make that fixed top nav 100% width and give it left `padding`?

Comment: i tried with padding-left: 230px but it stills hiding some of my divs on right corner, thought it was not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `calc` or anything fancy, it's simple as this. Of course you can make the sidebar be above the navbar if you'd like to, here it is below it.

**Note** that you can use `box-sizing: border-box` to make your life much easier.

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.body {
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">Blablabla</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

With your current styles, instead of `width:100%` (remove this), add `right:0`:

```
nav#fixed-nav-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 230px;
    right:0;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid #191b1b;
    background-color: #141616;
    border-bottom: 1px #252525 solid;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
nav#fixed-nav-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 230px;
  right:0;
  z-index: 9999;
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid #191b1b;
  background-color: #141616;
  border-bottom: 1px #252525 solid;
}

nav#nav-sided {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Helvetica"; /* Tahoma */
  color: #c1c1c1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 230px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
  border-right: 1px #252525 solid;
  z-index: 8888;
}
```

```html
<nav id="fixed-nav-top">
  <div id="top-main">

  </div>
  <div id="user-area">

  </div>
</nav>
<nav id="nav-sided">
  <div id="logo">
    <div class="main-logo">:)</div>
  </div>

  other stuffs
</nav>
```

Comment: Nice, that worked too! Is it better than using width: calc(100% - 230px) ?

Comment: it's more compatible with the older browsers - just depends what you want to support

Comment: Check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for browser support. I'd say it's safe to use: developers should not support IE8 anymore (that was  a kind of opinion actually), and all other browser do support it.

Answer (score 1):

style:

```
div{
  position:absolute;
  left:230px;
  right:0px;
}
```

example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz8pgo4h/1/)

or:

```
div{
  margin-left:230px;
}
```

example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz8pgo4h/3/)